# ASCIIEncoding does not support in Windows 8 Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have this code work in desktop app, but it doesn't work in Windows 8 Store app, because System.Text does not have `ASCIIEncoding` support anymore:

`tagdata` is a `byte array`.

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(tagdata).Trim();
```

Should I use UT8Encoding? I just want to convert the byte array into `ASCII` text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a start, I'd suggest using `Encoding.ASCII` everywhere instead of `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII` - the latter somewhat implies that the `ASCII` property is a member of the `ASCIIEncoding` class, which it's not.

If you know that your byte array *is* just ASCII text, then you can use [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) freely, as every character present in ASCII is represented the same way in both UTF-8 and ASCII.

If you want to check the validity first, you just need to check that every byte in the array is less than 128

```
bool isAscii = tagData.All(b => b < 128);
```